# I`m trying to apply linear-gradient to my body, but it doesn't work. Now, when I use radial-gradient it works. Why is that?

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I'm working with Sass and I decided to keep the colors inside a var(). So, I'm using :root as my scope declaration. I've already added min-height to my body and to my html based on information found at  developer.mozilla : https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

" Notes
If you set the background-image property of the  tag to a linear-gradient, the gradient won't fill the browser screen unless you also set the min-height property of the document root (e.g. the  tag) to 100%."

I've been trying some stuff like adding some margin to my body but nothing worked out. I've visited some forums but I couldn't solve my issue.

The variables are working properly because when I try `background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center, var(--color-primary-light), var(--color-primary-dark));` everything works fine. I would like to know why the background-image does not apply if I use linear-gradient but works when I use radial-gradient?

```css
 /* COLORS */

:root{
    --color-primary: #eb2f64;
    --color-primary-light: #FF3366;
    --color-primary-dark: #BA265D;

    --color-grey-light-1: #faf9f9;
    --color-grey-light-2: #f4f2f2;
    --color-grey-light-3: #f0eeee;
    --color-grey-light-4: #ccc;

    --color-grey-dark-1: #333;
    --color-grey-dark-2: #777;
    --color-grey-dark-3: #999;
}

/* ============================================================== */

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

*,
*::after,
*::before{
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

html{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 62.5%;
    min-height: 100vh;
}


body{

    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.6;

    background-image: linear-gradient(to left right, var(--color-primary-light), var(--color-primary-dark)); /* IT DOES NOT WORK*/  
    
   /*  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center, var(--color-primary-light), var(--color-primary-dark));  IT WORKS */

    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
    <body>

       <h1>Some content</h1>
      
    </body>
```

Comment: at `linear-gradient(to left right,...` `left right` seems to neither be a (singular) side nor a corner. Have you tried simply `to left` or `to left top`?

Comment: Yeap ! That solved my issue.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a correct value for the direction it works. "to left right" is not a direction, "to left" would be, "to left top" would work or an angle.

```css
 /* COLORS */

:root{
    --color-primary: #eb2f64;
    --color-primary-light: #FF3366;
    --color-primary-dark: #BA265D;

    --color-grey-light-1: #faf9f9;
    --color-grey-light-2: #f4f2f2;
    --color-grey-light-3: #f0eeee;
    --color-grey-light-4: #ccc;

    --color-grey-dark-1: #333;
    --color-grey-dark-2: #777;
    --color-grey-dark-3: #999;
}

/* ============================================================== */

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

*,
*::after,
*::before{
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

html{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 62.5%;
    min-height: 100vh;
}


body{

    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.6;

    background-image: linear-gradient(to left top, var(--color-primary-light), var(--color-primary-dark)); /* IT DOES NOT WORK*/  
    
   /*  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center, var(--color-primary-light), var(--color-primary-dark));  IT WORKS */

    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
    <body>

       <h1>Some content</h1>
      
    </body>
```